# Select sublist if element present in second list

Tags: python, list, selection

I have two lists:

```
A = [['67', '75', 'X'], ['85','72', 'V'], ['1','2', 'Y'],  ['3','5', 'X', 'Y']]
B = ['X', 'Y']
```

I want to create a third list, `C`, that have the sublists of `A` which have the elements defined on `B` (an / or).

```
C = [[67', '75', 'X'],['1','2', 'Y'],  ['3','5', 'X', 'Y']]
```

I have tried:

```
C = [i for i in B if i in A]
```

But it didn't work, I get an empty C list. Please let me know what would be the best approach to obtain C.

Comment: What if you have `['3', '5', 'X', 'V']` or `['3', '5', 'V', 'X']`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a list-comprehension that checks if any of the elements in `B` is in `A`:

```
A = [['67', '75', 'X'], ['85','72', 'V'], ['1','2', 'Y'], ['3','5', 'X', 'Y']]
B = ['X', 'Y']

C = [x for x in A if any(y in x for y in B)]
# [['67', '75', 'X'], ['1', '2', 'Y'], ['3', '5', 'X', 'Y']]
```

Comment: Beat me to it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
C = [y for y in A for x in B if x in y]
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this:

```
C = list()
for i in A:
    if B[0] in i or B[1] in i:
        C.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [set intersection](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection) to check if there is any element in common between the element `e` (sublist) of `A` and `b` defined as `set(B)`.

So,

```
b = set(B)
C = [ e for e in A if b.intersection(set(e)) ]

#=> [['67', '75', 'X'], ['1', '2', 'Y'], ['3', '5', 'X', 'Y']]
```